# Enable/Disable textfield with jQuery by clicking on a checkbox black-holed

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to write a function in jQuery that when a user click on a checkbox a textfield-2 becomes enabeled and required and textfield-1 becomes disabled. if checkbox is not checked, the textfield-2 is disabled and not required and textfield-1 is enabeled.

So is like a toggle between these 2 textfield. the form is sth like this:

```
   <form id="link" name="link" action="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="url_type" id="url_type"  >
   <input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1">
   <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" disable="disable">
   <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
   </form>
```

And the jQuery Code looks like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#url_type').on('change',function(){
       var checked=$('#url_type').is(':checked');
        if(checked==true)
        {   
            $('#textfield1').attr('disabled',true);
            $('#textfield2').attr('disabled',false);
        } else {

            $('#textfield1').attr('disabled',false);
            $('#textfield2').attr('disabled',true);
        }
      });
</script>
```

The problem i have is that at cakephp when i create a new link, if the checkbox is not selected works fine, but if i check the checkbox, ( meaning that textfield2 becomes enabled and textfield1 disabled ) it generate an error that looks like this:

**The request has been black-holed Error: The requested address was not found on this server.**

I donn't know where the conflict is or what is generating that error!

Comment: It has probably something todo with the [`SecurityComponent`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#security). Check the [`csrf`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#csrf-configuration) section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [Blackhole issue](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#handling-blackhole-callbacks).

Put the following line in `beforeFilter method` of your controller class file.

```
$this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'blackhole';
```

Now, create a function in the same controller file:

```
public function blackhole($type) {
// handle errors.
}
```

[This post](http://laffers.net/blog/2011/01/03/advanced-blackhole-callback-cakephp-security-component/) can also help you to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt your form tag:
1. use type: post
2. type an url in attribute action, where your form should be sent (/name of Controller/name of Action)

```
   <form id="link" name="link" method="post" action="/controller/action">
   <input type="checkbox" name="url_type" id="url_type"  >
   <input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1">
   <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2">
   <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
   </form>
```

Comment: is not a bad redirect of the form because if i don't disable attribute on textfield2 it works perfect...

Comment: But you mentioned the Error: The requested address was not found on this server.

Comment: I suppose, there are futher dependencies, not shown on your posted code.

Comment: yes i know but that error is shown only when i use the jQuery function for enable/disable textfield based on the checkbox, otherwise it works perfect.

Comment: Please compare the successful and failing requested by exmaining your requested data via Firefox´s Firebug or IE Developer Tools -> Tab Network. The difference might to be responsible.

Comment: As far as i can tell, or as far as i know the one generating the error is disable="disable" attribute on the textfield2. but i just dont know y :/

Comment: As far as i can tell, or as far as i know the one generating the error is disable="disable" attribute on the textfield2. but i just dont know y :/

Comment: I suggest an server-side mistake dependent on the field `textfield2`. Con you please post your concerning controller for that view?